# How to get Items of a Listview in an another Listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi I am beginer in Android. I have created an app which implements listview to display the items stored in an arraylist. I would now like to get those stored listview items in to an another listview which is in another activity. Can some one help me on how to do it??